# Cannot create enrollement token : Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, elastic-stack, keystore, elk

My current ELK version is 8.10

I have a working cluster with 2 node

- 1 Master + Data
- 1 Data only

I did not use the auto setup of ELK and created certificates (SSL + HTTP) using the `elasticsearch-certutil` tool.

I followed the procedure and communication are encrypted between Master and data node 1.
However when I want to add data node 2, Master reject the request. I tried to create a enrollement token using `elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token -s node` but I get the following error :

```
Elasticsearch node HTTP layer SSL configuration Keystore doesn’t contain any PrivateKey entries where the associated certificate is a CA certificate
```

Tried to follow this this [fix](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/import-ca-cert-as-privatekeyentry-to-http-keystore-solve-unable-to-create-enrollment-token-error/313780) but keytool ask me for a password I did not set up for my certificates (I put blank everywhere for test)